# Mule RSS Feed Splitter: Issues with splitting certain feeds into SyndEntry objects

Tags: xml, rss, feed, mule, split

I'm having issues using the RSS feed splitter in Mule to split RSS feeds from some websites into individual SyndEntry objects. I have included xml code from my Mule application. I have also included the logs of 3 different instances of running my Mule application on 3 different feeds ( the first works and the next two gives errors ). Don't worry about the output of the first feed on the bottom, but I have included it there to show that some feeds can indeed be turned (splitted) into SyndEntry objects, and subsequently elements can be extracted from those objects ( by my EntryReceiver class defined in my Mule application ). Yet, for most of the other feeds that I try to split, I end up getting the same errors. Please help me if you can.

Note: I also included a snippet of the EntryReceiver class at the end whose function takes in a SyndEntry object, yet the feeds that give errors never enter the function in the first place.

Mule Application Code...

```
 <http:polling-connector name="PollingHttpConnector" pollingFrequency="60000" doc:name="HTTP Polling" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape"  receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true"/>
    <flow name="myFlow" doc:name="myFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"   doc:name="HTTP" address="http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss" connector-ref="PollingHttpConnector"/>
        <rss:feed-splitter/>
        <rss:entry-last-updated-filter/>
        <component class="path.to.EntryReceiver" doc:name="Java"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${my.host}" port="${my.port}" path="api/v1/activity" method="POST" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

RossMason Feed (WORKING)... from http://rossmason.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

```
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=279b9b1a-e979-11e2-ba08-0d15b2b474eb
  payload=org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    Cache-Control=private, max-age=0
    Connection=false
    Content-Type=application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
    Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 15:55:33 GMT
    ETag=W/"CUUBQXs6cCl7ImA9WhJbFkQ."
    Expires=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 15:55:33 GMT
    Keep-Alive=false
    Last-Modified=Wed, 26 Sep 2012 21:00:50 GMT
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.http.rossmason.blogspot.com.feeds.posts.default
    Server=GSE
    Transfer-Encoding=chunked
    X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
    http.headers={ETag=W/"CUUBQXs6cCl7ImA9WhJbFkQ.", X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, Expires=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 15:55:33 GMT, Last-Modified=Wed, 26 Sep 2012 21:00:50 GMT, Connection=false, Server=GSE, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, Cache-Control=private, max-age=0, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 15:55:33 GMT, Keep-Alive=false, Content-Type=application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8}
    http.method=GET
    http.query.params={}
    http.query.string=
    http.request=http://rossmason.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
    http.status=200
    http.version=HTTP/1.1
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
}

org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: { "priority" : 0.1 , "actor" : { "objectType" : "person" , "id" : "Ross Mason" , "displayName" : "Strategy is Something You Can Only Learn"} , "verb" : "post" , "object" : { "url" : "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-1425601518852438157.post-6101490854635104494" , "objectType" : "notification" , "author" : "Ross Mason" , "content" : { "text" : "There is a great post by Mike Cannon-Brookes of Altassian, which talks about how they came up with the stellar business strategy that has that has dri..." , "url" : "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-1425601518852438157.post-6101490854635104494" , "urlLinkName" : "Complete News Article"}} , "published" : { "$date" : "2008-12-12T13:22:00.000Z"} , "target" : "public"}
```

NASA Feed (NOT WORKING)... from http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss

```
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=f33625a5-e97a-11e2-aeec-ff1013508cd8
  payload=org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=utf-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    Cache-Control=no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Connection=true
    Content-Language=en
    Content-Length=6831
    Content-Type=application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8
    Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:08:07 GMT
    ETag="1373472427"
    Expires=Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
    Keep-Alive=true
    Last-Modified=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:07:07 +0000
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.http.www.nasa.gov.rss.dyn.breaking.news.rss
    Server=nginx/1.4.1
    Vary=Accept-Encoding
    Via=1.0 690ebb4ae180f02f630cd90d73b6bc50.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    X-Amz-Cf-Id=nyC1SZiI_0AKB7EUZ1S6w53_TGV3BrsDlY0vpxPpQ0xLXv4KKGRn-g==
    X-Cache=RefreshHit from cloudfront
    X-Powered-By=PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
    http.headers={Content-Language=en, ETag="1373472427", Content-Length=6831, Expires=Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT, Last-Modified=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:07:07 +0000, X-Amz-Cf-Id=nyC1SZiI_0AKB7EUZ1S6w53_TGV3BrsDlY0vpxPpQ0xLXv4KKGRn-g==, Connection=true, Server=nginx/1.4.1, X-Powered-By=PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6, X-Cache=RefreshHit from cloudfront, Cache-Control=no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:08:07 GMT, Vary=Accept-Encoding, Keep-Alive=true, Via=1.0 690ebb4ae180f02f630cd90d73b6bc50.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), Content-Type=application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8}
    http.method=GET
    http.query.params={}
    http.query.string=
    http.request=http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss
    http.status=200
    http.version=HTTP/1.0
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_ENCODING=utf-8

********************************************************************************
Message               : null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: ReleasingInputStream
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.module.rss.routing.FeedSplitter$EntryComparator:121 (null)
2. null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: ReleasingInputStream (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:35 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.rss.routing.FeedSplitter$EntryComparator.compare(FeedSplitter.java:121)
    at org.mule.module.rss.routing.FeedSplitter$EntryComparator.compare(FeedSplitter.java:117)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:530)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=16f3ed76-e97b-11e2-aeec-ff1013508cd8
  payload=org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=utf-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    Cache-Control=no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Connection=true
    Content-Encoding=gzip
    Content-Language=en
    Content-Length=2118
    Content-Type=application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8
    Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:09:13 GMT
    ETag="1373472468"
    Expires=Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
    Keep-Alive=true
    Last-Modified=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:07:48 +0000
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.http.www.nasa.gov.rss.dyn.breaking.news.rss
    Server=nginx/1.4.1
    Vary=Accept-Encoding
    Via=1.0 0fc90446797ad54b123cb72bd8f4f142.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    X-Amz-Cf-Id=83X6Bc8fZjAU98-991DN8rnruZDRNw9O_N_W0eXI7iHv7Z7N5aurZg==
    X-Cache=Miss from cloudfront
    X-Powered-By=PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
    http.headers={Content-Language=en, ETag="1373472468", Content-Length=2118, Expires=Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT, Last-Modified=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:07:48 +0000, X-Amz-Cf-Id=83X6Bc8fZjAU98-991DN8rnruZDRNw9O_N_W0eXI7iHv7Z7N5aurZg==, Connection=true, X-Powered-By=PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6, Server=nginx/1.4.1, X-Cache=Miss from cloudfront, Cache-Control=no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:09:13 GMT, Vary=Accept-Encoding, Content-Encoding=gzip, Keep-Alive=true, Via=1.0 0fc90446797ad54b123cb72bd8f4f142.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), Content-Type=application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8}
    http.method=GET
    http.query.params={}
    http.query.string=
    http.request=http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss
    http.status=200
    http.version=HTTP/1.0
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_ENCODING=utf-8org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. (com.sun.syndication.io.ParsingFeedException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Content is not allowed in prolog. (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)
  org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper:-1 (null)
2. Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. (org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException)
  org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder:533 (null)
3. Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. (com.sun.syndication.io.ParsingFeedException)
  com.sun.syndication.io.WireFeedInput:182 (null)
4. Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. (com.sun.syndication.io.ParsingFeedException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.rss.transformers.ObjectToRssFeed:85 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

ESPN Feed (NOT WORKING)...

```
from... http://search.espn.go.com/rss/bill-simmons/

org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=32be248e-e97a-11e2-9817-fb41b80baff3
  payload=org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=iso-8859-1
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    Cache-Control=max-age=600
    Connection=true
    Content-Type=text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1
    Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:03:03 GMT
    Keep-Alive=true
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.http.search.espn.go.com.rss.bill.simmons
    P3P=CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa PSAa PSDa IVAi IVDi CONi OUR SAMo OTRo BUS PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA PRE"
    Set-Cookie=[Lorg.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;@b07c615
    Transfer-Encoding=chunked
    http.headers={Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2013 16:03:03 GMT, P3P=CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa PSAa PSDa IVAi IVDi CONi OUR SAMo OTRo BUS PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA PRE", Keep-Alive=true, Set-Cookie=[Lorg.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;@b07c615, Connection=true, Content-Type=text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1, Cache-Control=max-age=600}
    http.method=GET
    http.query.params={}
    http.query.string=
    http.request=http://search.espn.go.com/rss/bill-simmons/
    http.status=200
    http.version=HTTP/1.1
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_ENCODING=iso-8859-1

org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: ReleasingInputStream
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.module.rss.routing.FeedSplitter$EntryComparator:121 (null)
2. null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: ReleasingInputStream (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:35 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.rss.routing.FeedSplitter$EntryComparator.compare(FeedSplitter.java:121)
    at org.mule.module.rss.routing.FeedSplitter$EntryComparator.compare(FeedSplitter.java:117)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:530)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

EntryReceiver class snippet...

```
public class EntryReceiver {

    public String readEntry(@Payload SyndEntry entry) throws Exception
    {

        char[] descCharArray = entry.getDescription().getValue().toString().toCharArray();

        String summary = "";

        int contentLength = entry.getDescription().getValue().toString().length();

        for (int i = 0; i < contentLength; i++){
            if(i == 150) break;
            else{
                summary = summary + descCharArray[i];
            }
        }

        summary = summary.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");



        BasicDBObject activity = new BasicDBObject();       
        activity.put("priority", new Double(0.1) );

        // ACTOR
        BasicDBObject actor = new BasicDBObject();
        actor.put("objectType", "person");
        actor.put("id", entry.getAuthor());
        actor.put("displayName", entry.getTitle());


        activity.put("actor", actor);
        activity.put("verb", "post");

        // OBJECT
        BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject();
        object.put("url", entry.getUri());

        object.put("objectType", "notification");
        object.put("author", entry.getAuthor());

        activity.put("object", object);


        activity.put("published", entry.getPublishedDate());
        activity.put("target", "public");

        return activity.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the later two feeds do not follow the date format standard specified by RSS standards (RFC 822) for the  element. And because of this Mule's FeedSplitter is not able to parse these dates.

See http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html for the standard RSS schema.

RFC 822 is here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt